# Laravel changing env values dynamically

Tags: php, laravel-5, installation

I'm using Brotzka Env Editor.  I'm creating a page to connect to a newly created database.  In my .env I have this values

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=xxx
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I managed to change the DB_DATABASE and DB_PASSWORD to SHOP and P@ssw0rd respectively by running this code

```
$env = new DotenvEditor();
$env->changeEnv([
   'DB_HOST' => $request['hostname'],
   'DB_DATABASE' => $request['dbname'],
   'DB_USERNAME' => $request['username'],
   'DB_PASSWORD' => $request['dbpassword'],
]);

 $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:clear');
 $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');

 DB::connection()->getPdo();
```

But on DB:connection()-getPdo() line I'm getting error like

```
[2017-12-27 06:42:15] local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'XXXXX'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in C:\alaracart\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:43
```

which is still the old .env values.   What could be the 'reset' command to reload laravel again?  thanks.

Comment: this `Access denied for user 'XXXXX'@'localhost'` error throws when username and password is wrong

Comment: **I managed to change the DB_DATABASE and DB_PASSWORD to SHOP and P@ssw0rd respectively by running this code** what you trying to  archive ?? no idea with this

Comment: you don't need any package for changing database just put in env  for two database crds and change config acc to req. if you need any help in that feal free to ask

Comment: changeEnv does change the .env file with my new db username, database name and password but the error message is still throwing the old values in the env file.

Comment: Actually what I'm trying to achieve is how can i reload the site so that the new env values will take effect?   I'm creating an installation routine wherein i need to show a view that the user can enter database user name and password

Answer (score 0):

You need change questions to "Change Default Database connection Dynamically"
this is the answer to that, but it will solve your problem.

changing env value not affective in current request or process. if you need changes direct config values.

For example changes current database connnection data base name in request time.

```
//get old dbname
$oldDbName = env("DB_DATABASE");


$env = new DotenvEditor();
$env->changeEnv([
   'DB_HOST' => $request['hostname'],
   'DB_DATABASE' => $request['dbname'],
   'DB_USERNAME' => $request['username'],
   'DB_PASSWORD' => $request['dbpassword'],
]);

DB::disconnect(env("DB_CONNECTION"));

Config::set('database.connections.' . env("DB_CONNECTION"), array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql', //or $request['driver'],
        'host'      => $request['hostname'],
        'database'  => $request['dbname'],
        'username'  => $request['username'],
        'password'  => $request['dbpassword'],
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
));

//Trying reconnect database
try {
        DB::connection()->getPdo();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //revert old db if any error
        DB::disconnect(env("DB_CONNECTION"));
        Config::set('database.connections.' . env("DB_CONNECTION") .'.database', $oldDbName );
    }
```

helpfull link:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-change-default-database-connection-dynamically?page=1

Comment: @Kruze pls, wait for yours result.